# *searching* for color changes in less

Tags: search, color, less

I have `less` already displaying colored output (e.g. from Vagrant or Packer) by having the `LESS` environment variable set to `-R`.

What I'd like to be able to do now is to search for specific colors, e.g. `ESC[1;31m` for red.

I tried various combinations (e.g. `\[1;31m`) but it seems that `less` ignores them in its search when in `-R` mode. When I toggle `-R` off it finds them, though.  This could make sense when you think of it because the entire sequence is considered as having "zero width" so there is nothing for `less` to show when it finds it.

Is there another trick I can use?

To recap - the aim is to keep viewing colored output but also be able to search the color escape sequence at the same time.

Comment: Can't vouch for it, but there is something about this in  the [Unix and Linux forum](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149614/less-command-change-color-of-and-end).

Comment: @Colt thanks but unfortunately the question you link to is about colorising less' search output, not about finding existing color sequences. :(

Comment: Ahh, yes, that is what you said! It seems that the `-R` is what is supposed to do this, but it also seems that it is problematic.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @ewwhite I want this in order to find errors in command output. e.g. "Puppet" already marks errors in red color. Searching for "Error: " works most of the time but I recently found such strings in non-error lines which I have to keep skipping.

Comment: @AmosShapira That _may_ be the wrong approach to this. But let's see if anyone has a better idea.